# How to properly use the /e command from GNU sed

Tags: regex, sed, gnu

I am trying to wrap my head around the `/e` command from GNU sed. It turns out that it is very tricky to get it work as expected.

(Please note that in the examples, below I am not claiming that sed is the perfect tool for the job, but it serves just as a minimal example using `/e` command. So please kindly do not suggest any solution with AWK).

I have the following input file:

**input.txt:**

```
10.5+8 50.5-30.2 7+5
```

- **Assumptions**:

- No space/tab between the binary operators and the numbers.
- Spaces/tabs are used ONLY as separators between expressions.

My attempt is to use the `/e` command to invoke `bc` commad to evaluate the expressions.

The **expected output** is:

```
18.5 20.3 12
```

```
sed -E "s/([^ \t]+)/echo '\1' | bc /e" input.txt
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
File 50.5-30.2 is unavailable.
```

Questions:

- Could someone please explain how does the command `/e` work? I have tried reading the manual over and over but I am still confused.
- How can  I fix the command above to get the expected output?

Comment: any particular reason to use a regex tool to do math ?

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto: Yes, the example above may seem inappropriate. But it is solely to demonstrate the use of `/e` command. In fact, in my real problem, I needed to use `calc` command instead of `bc` in order to convert the floating number format from scientific to normal (that is `xx.xxxxxxx` instead of `x.xxxeN`)

Comment: then why not use something like `awk` or even `python` that likely makes life easier for math-related tasks

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto: Because awk/python are slow, and personally I don't like awk.

Comment: then you REALLY don't know awk - i routinely benchmark my interpreted `awk` scripts directly against compiled C-binaries, and a lot of times it even beats it. Just think how insane that must be for interpreted scripts without just-in-time compilation to actually beat compiled C-code binaries

Comment: case in point - i wrote my own `awk` based `wc` replacement cuz i found *both* `gnu-wc` and `bsd-wc` to be too slow for my needs.

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto: I have written several awk scripts but I never consider myself knowing awk. But tbh, I hate it; I enjoy using very long sed commands rather than using a single awk command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `gnu-sed` command to fix it:

```bash
sed -E 's/[^ \t]+/printf -- "$(echo & | bc) ";/ge' file

18.5 20.3 12
```

Or if you want output in different lines then:

```bash
sed -E 's/[^ \t]+/echo & | bc;/ge' file

18.5
20.3
12
```

Terminator `\n`  or `;` after command is important to tell `sed` to run `printf` or `echo` once for each match.

Comment: Sorry, But I need to use `bc` instead of using bash to evlauate the expressions

Comment: Sorry but you wrote using `sed` is important for you

Comment: This worked for me: `sed -E 's/[^ \t]+/printf "%s " "$(echo & | bc)"\n/ge' input.txt
`

Comment: Another way to use `bc` is to keep it outside `sed`: `sed -E 's~[^ \t]+~echo "&"\n~ge' file | bc` or may be this: `sed -E 's/[^ \t]+/printf "%s " "$(bc <<< &)"\n/ge' file`

Comment: The new version doesn't seem to wrok. I am getting this error: `sh: 1: Syntax error: redirection unexpected`

Comment: I think the "herestring" won't work since `sh` is used instead of `bash`. Changing the herestring to a pipe works.

Comment: It worked for me on MAC, may be `/bin/sh` on MAC supports it.

Comment: You can also try my updated answer.

Comment: In the last sentence: Terminator `\n` doesn't appear in the commands.

Comment: Indeed `;` or `\n` are just the command terminators, not part of commands.

Comment: Hi, I found a "bug" in the command above, printf has problems printing negative numbers. So, to solve that, one should use `printf --` instead.

Comment: Yes that's a good point.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed,shell and bc):

```
echo '10.5+8 50.5-30.2 7+5' | sed 'y/ \t/;;/;s/.*/echo "&" | bc/e;y/\n/ /'
```

Convert echoed string into a bc input by translating spaces to `;`'s.

Use the contents of the pattern space and echo it into bc via a pipeline.

Take the result of bc and translate newlines to spaces.

Comment: This won't work as it assumes there is only a single space between expressions.

Comment: I have tried to edit the command, but the edit queue is full, here is another version that assumes an arbitrary horizontal whtitespace between expressions: `sed  -E 's/[ \t]+/;/g;s/.*/echo "&" | bc /e;y/\n/ /'  input.txt `

Comment: @Algerian_Amazigh_05 it does work for multiple spaces and now for mutilple tabs too.